# iOS Swift - Question about semaphores and sequencing in Bluetooth Low Energy Manager

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm looking at the open source Bluefruit code as an example, specifically the BleManager class that is the interface with the CBCentralManager. I've emailed the author and they didn't respond:

[Bluefruit BleManager class](https://github.com/adafruit/Bluefruit_LE_Connect_v2/blob/master/Bluefruit/AdafruitKit/Ble/BleCentralMode/BleManager.swift)

It looks like the class is designed in a singleton architecture ("shared" on line 23) and so is constructed lazily when the first "BleManager.connect() is called elsewhere in the code.

What confuses me is in the init(), there's a semaphore "wait" function:

```
override init() {
    super.init()

    centralManagerPoweredOnSemaphore.wait()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background), options: [:])
//        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main, options: [:])
    }
```

I'm really only used to semaphores in a DispatchQueue.async() thread. Isn't this wait() function being called on a main thread? Won't that lock it up? The .signal() call that will unblock that .wait() call is on line 289:

```
extension BleManager: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

        DLog("centralManagerDidUpdateState: \(central.state.rawValue)")
        // Unlock state lock if we have a known state
        if central.state == .poweredOn || central.state == .poweredOff || central.state == .unsupported || central.state == .unauthorized {
            centralManagerPoweredOnSemaphore.signal()
        }
```

So once the system centralManager updates the BLE utility state, this will get called, and as long as it's not unknown, .signal() will get called and the rest of the init() will run. I've used print statements to confirm this is how it works. centralManagerPoweredOnSemaphore.wait() is called, then centralManagerDidUpdateState(), and then the rest of the init(). I still don't understand this though:

- How did did the semaphore .wait() on the main thread not lock everything up? For example look at line 169 and 170. What does that do?
- How is centralManagerDidUpdateState() called when the delegate hasn't been assigned yet? It seems like the delegate gets assigned in the bottom of the init() that isn't called right away before this function. How does the system CBCentralManager know to use that specific centralManagerDidUpdateState() function?
- How exactly do the CBCentralManager states work? I've read through the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518888-centralmanagerdidupdatestate) but it's not too descriptive. It seems that when ["Core Bluetooth initializes or resets" it will be "unknown"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmanagerstate/unknown). And then after a certain period of time, will it always change to a known state, based on if the device has the capability and what the user settings/permissions are? So I'm guessing that's why it's "safe" to block the rest of the class until we get a response. But what "initializes" the Core Bluetooth in this case? As far as I can tell, with the partial init() and before centralManagerDidUpdateState(), there were no calls to any Core Bluetooth functions. What made Core Bluetooth try to initialize the BLE utility and update the state? It looks like this BleManager class is called lazily, so it can't have been anything at a higher level.

In the end it works though, I just wonder how the exact sequence of things is actually running under the hood to make it run properly.

Comment: Merely saying `wait` to a semaphore doesn't block the current thread. The semaphore has a _count_. `wait` decrements the count, but it doesn't block anything unless the count falls below zero. Here, the value starts at `1` and the immediate `wait` decrements it to zero, and _now_ we are ready to starting the _wait-and-signal_ game of blocking (on background threads).

Comment: The uses of semaphores that you may have seen might be wrong. Semaphores are about making sure only one "person" at a time gets ownership of / communication with a shared resource. — The question as posed is extremely broad (and gets broader as it goes along); it would be helpful to ask just one thing at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My reference on semaphores was here:
https://medium.com/@roykronenfeld/semaphores-in-swift-e296ea80f860

They always seem to be in the scope of a DispatchQueue and we're explicitly told to not run the .wait() command on the main thread. It may not be thorough though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are using the semaphore to block any operations on the `BleManager` object until the central exits the `.unknown` state.

The semaphore is created with an initial value of 1. The `wait` in the `init` will decrement it to 0, and not block. The central is then initialised and at some point the powered on state is entered.  At this point the `signal` will return the semaphore to 1.

Now looking at the other functions, such as the `connect` function (line 167) you will see the first thing they do is `wait` and then `signal` the semaphore. Consider what happens in two different states:

1. The central is not yet in the `.poweredOn` state - the semaphore count is 0 so the `wait` blocks. Assuming the BLE state becomes `.poweredOn` at some point, the `wait` will end and the semaphore is immediately released and then the `connect` function proceeds.
2. The central is already in the `.poweredOn` state - the semaphore count is 1, so the `wait` does not block, the semaphore is then immediately released and the `connect` function proceeds.

The other functions work in a similar way.

The advantage of this approach is that the calling code doesn't need to keep checking the state; it can access the `sharedInstance` and then immediately call `startScan` without needing to check that the Central is powered on.

Comment: Got it, that all makes sense, thank you. Last question, what "turns on" the BleManager object and tells is to "power up" though?

Comment: The user turns Bluetooth on and off. Unless the user has turned it off, you will get a `.poweredOn` state very soon after you initialise the `CBCentralManager`

Comment: So if Bluetooth is `.poweredon` at a system level before you start the app, is it possible that `centralManagerDidUpdateState()` is never called? Because the state is static for the whole lifecycle of the app? 

Or does something in the app somehow initialize `CBCentralManager` so that it goes through these first state changes?

Comment: No, the states are logical states for the `CBCentralManager` instance. Core Bluetooth is an abstraction layer. It always starts in '.unknown`.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but then I still don't get the sequencing. I can use print statements and see that `centralManagerDidUpdateState()` is run before the CBCentralManager init of `centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background), options: [:])`

There should be no instance of a CBCentralManager before line 48 is run, yet the callback is still called.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `print` statements.  Set breakpoints.  You can also look at the address of the `CBCentralManager` that you init and what is passed to the delegate method to confirm that they are the same instance.